# std::chrono and missing (?) support for negative leap seconds

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-chrono, leap-second

C++20 added time zone support to `std::chrono`, and this includes [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second). However, it appears as if only leap second insertion was supported, not leap second removal, that is, negative leap seconds. (Admittedly, since 1972 there only have been positive leap seconds; but it seems that in the last few years the drift has reversed, and a negative leap second seems possible in the upcoming years.)

This is evident from the way the `std::chrono::leap_second` class is described - there's no way to tell positive from negative leap seconds.

Is it known why `std::chrono` doesn't support this possibility? Was this an optimization, or a mistake of some sort? Or is it supported already and I have missed something?

Note: The MSVC implementation seems to have a nonstandard feature that allows negative leap seconds.

Comment: While a good topic for discussion, this isn't really the right place for such discussions. Please take some time to refresh ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`[time.zone.leap.members]/2`](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/time.zone.leap) actually does specify negative leap seconds.

> Returns: +1s to indicate a positive leap second or -1s to indicate a negative leap second.
> [Note 1: All leap seconds inserted up through 2019 were positive leap seconds. — end note]

When the standard speaks of insertion of a leap second, that leap second could be negative, which would be the same as a removal.

Note: I am unsure if this is new to C++23 or also in C++20, I don't have a copy of the C++20 draft with me right now.

Comment: FWIW, you can get live drafts of all the modern standards here: https://github.com/timsong-cpp/cppwp

Comment: Indeed, `std::chrono::leap_second` seems to have grown a further function member in C++23: `constexpr seconds value() const noexcept;` This allows the distinction between positive and negative leap seconds that was missing before.

Comment: @NathanOliver's link to Tim Song's repository of all modern standards indicates that `leap_second::value()`, with its reference to negative leap seconds, was present in C++20: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/time.zone.leap#members-2  Clear language for negative leap seconds was introduced via LWG issue 3359 prior to and accepted in time for C++20: https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3359

Comment: @Howard Hinnant: Thanks for this! I was checking against n4800, and `value()` isn't in there, so it must have been a very late addition to C++20.